# Moving custom objects in A-Frame using super-hands

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to move an object (in this case a piece of bread), using super-hands, but the object isn't moving when grabbed. There is no interaction between the controllers and the object.

```
<a-sphere hoverable grabbable strechable draggable droppable
color="red" position="1 1 0" scale=".1 .1 .1"></a-sphere>

<a-entity hoverable grabbable stretchable draggable droppable
scale="0.01 0.01 0.01" position="0 2 0" dynamic-body="shape: auto;mass: 0"
obj-model="obj:assets/models/bread/source/Brown Bread.obj;mtl:assets/models/bread/source/Brown Bread.mtl" ></a-entity>
```

The documentation seems to suggest that just adding the reaction components should give it interaction, but nothing is happening.

Edit: Using https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component

Comment: Are you able to move the sphere but not the bread?

Comment: Yes, the sphere moves, but the bread doesn't

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? I am facing the same issue. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities with dynamic bodies can only be moved through the physics system, so `grabbable` handles the movement with a physics `constraint` (assuming you have added a `static-body` to the controller entity or allowed `progressive-controls` to do it for you). However, a `dynamic-body` with `mass: 0`, as you have it, is immovable (it's actually treated as a `static-body` by the physics engine).

If you want to keep the body from falling, set `physics="gravity: 0` instead. To keep it from floating away, set damping values on the body component closer to 1.